# Set livewire rendered blade as bootstrap popover data-content

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, bootstrap-popover

I want to show customer data in a bootstrap popover.

I am using livewire datatable to show customers.
when click customer user name I want to show a popover with customer details.

this is the table which I show user name
[image]

user name get by this code

```html
<div>
    <a title="simulate" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" 
      data-placement="bottom" href="javascript:void(0);" 
      onclick="openCustomerPopup('{{ $user->id }}')">
      {{ $user->first_name .' ' .$user->last_name}}</a>
</div>
<script>
function openCustomerPopup(customerId) {
    console.log(customerId);
    @this.emit('showUserPopover', customerId);
}

function closePopover() {
    @this.emit('closeUserPopover');
}

</script>
```

This is the livewire to get the customer details

```html
class CustomerPopover extends Component
{
    public $isOpen = false;
    public $customer = null;

    protected $listeners = [
        'closeUserPopover',
        'showUserPopover' => 'open',
    ];

    public function open($customerId)
    {
        $this->customer = CustomerFacade::get($customerId);
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function closeUserPopover()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.customer-popover');
    }
   }
```

this is the blade which i call from livewire

```html
<div>
    @if($isOpen)
    <div>
        <h3>{{ $customer->first_name }}</h3>
        <div>{{ $customer->last_name }}</div>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

How can I show this rendering blade as popover's "data-content"

If anyone know it is helpful..